# Open a url in new tab using jquery on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Open a url in new tab using jquery on page load**
I want that a new tab open load a url on some page load.

I am trying something like

```
<a href="[SOME_URL]" id="new_lnk_opener" target="_blank">New Tab</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#new_lnk_opener').trigger('click');      
   });
    </script>
```

But it is not working. Click event is not triggered.
I can do it with Javascript 'open' function. But i don't want to use it as it is blocked by most browsers.

I want is trigger jquery click event on link automatically and open a new window/tab.

Send some code or suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Well, it is blocked for an obvious reason

Comment: "The correct way to do this is blocked by some browsers, give me a hack that works" is hardly a real question. **If** your question had an answer with an alternative, it'd be too localized as the browser or anti-popup in question would fix it sooner or later.

Comment: If your application actually requires a popup, you can try opening it inside an `iframe` or use a modal instead. If you're trying to place ads there, the current hack is to open it in a `$(document).one('mousedown', function(){ window.open('url'); })` so the first click in the page will open it, though it is extremely dirty and every user hates that.

Comment: I am using it for ads.

Comment: Google, uh, `Kate Middleton` or `Jessica Biel`, click randomly on links, wait for a site which successfully brandishes popups on page load, right-click `View Source`, success! Rinse, repeat per browser. (Note, do not do this.)

Comment: @FaisalHussain ...and that's why the popup blockers were invented in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly control this, because it can be configured by the user.You shouldn't rely on a new tab being opened. The user may have their browser settings set to open a new tab when a popup window is opened or it may show up as a popup. It just all depends on the browser settings.

**EDIT:**

A workaround with some limitations is available [here](http://www.paulsilver.co.uk/code/html_working_popup.php).

Comment: `window.open`, without resulting from user interaction, is usually blocked by most browsers. I guess that is what OP meant.

Comment: I already Told i dont want to use open as it is blocked in browser. I want is trigger jquery click event on link automatically and open a new window/tab.

Comment: @FaisalHussain The browser blocks automated popup windows. There's nothing you can do about it. The browsers don't block popup windows just to make life harder for developers; if you happen to find a workaround, it's most likely a bug in the browser.

Comment: @FaisalHussain - You can't emulate IO events successfully with JS in a browser, which is what `event.click()` would need to do succeed. Otherwise, EVERY OTHER AD NETWORK would just do that to get around the restrictions.